# Alignment of imageview in tablelayout

Tags: java, android, alignment, android-imageview, tablelayout

This should be easy, how can I align the star in the middle. I'm adding the top header textviews and stars dynamically in code. I tried setting gravity on the imageview did not work.

UPDATE: I added `iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_START)` now star aligns to left

[image]
[image]

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads">
   <TableLayout  
    android:id="@+id/TableAch"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:shrinkColumns="*"
    android:stretchColumns="*"
    >

        <TableRow  
        android:id="@+id/RowAchTitle"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"  
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        >  

            <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/ViewAchTitle"  
                android:layout_width="match_parent"  
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
                android:textStyle="bold"  
                android:text="Achievements"  
                android:gravity="center"  
                android:layout_span="6">
            </TextView>  

        </TableRow>  
       <TableRow  
        android:id="@+id/RowAchHeader"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="6"
        >   
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>



    </RelativeLayout>
```

---

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.acheivements);

            tbLayout = (TableLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.TableAch);
            rowHeader = (TableRow) this.findViewById(R.id.RowAchHeader);

            FlurryAgent.logEvent("Achievements"); 

            TableRow.LayoutParams tableRowParams=
                      new TableRow.LayoutParams
                      (TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            tableRowParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 5);


            TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            params.weight = 1;
            params.gravity= Gravity.CENTER;

            int fontSize = 12;

            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setLayoutParams(params);
            tv.setText("     ");
            tv.setTextSize(fontSize);
            rowHeader.addView(tv); //This is blank top left corner

            for (Level level : Level.values()) { //Then we add all the headers for games
                tv = new TextView(this);

                tv.setText("EASY");
                tv.setTextSize(fontSize);
                tv.setLayoutParams(params);
                rowHeader.addView(tv);
            }

            //Next we add the levels for each game, putting a pass image where passed



            for (Games  game : Games.values()) {
                TableRow newRow = new TableRow(this);
                newRow.setLayoutParams(tableRowParams);

                String[] words = game.name().split("(?=[A-Z])");
                String name = "";
                for (String word : words) {
                    if(word.length() < 1) continue;
                    name += word + "\n";
                }

                tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setTextSize(fontSize);
                tv.setText(name);
                tv.setLayoutParams(params);
                newRow.addView(tv);
                newRow.setWeightSum(6);

                for (Level level : Level.values()) {
                    ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);

                        iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_START);
                    iv.setLayoutParams(params);

                    tv = new TextView(this);
                    tv.setLayoutParams(params);
                    tv.setText("EASY");
                    tv.setTextSize(fontSize);

                    if( acheivements.getPassed(level, game) )//has achievement
                    {
                        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.star_gold_full_small);
                    }
                    else {
                        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.star_gold_empty_small);
                    }
                    newRow.addView(tv);
                }
                tbLayout.addView(newRow);
            }

            setupAds(true);
     }
```

Comment: assign weightsum to TableRow and give weight to imageview and textviews to set perfectly on the screen.

Comment: i don't think so. weight is defined for amount of space it will occupy of its parent.

Comment: i want to see your updated code.

Comment: can u post image of current updated view.??

Comment: i think the prob is you have given weightsum 6. and you have used only 4 weight. when you are using weight you should use all weightsum. means total off allocated weight to textviews needs to be 6. pls do that and check the alignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do this:

```
TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0,WRAP_CONTENT);
```

you should have layout params of tablerow for textviews.

then in this params you should add weight.

```
params.weight = 1;
params.gravity = GRAVITY.CENTER;
```

and your table row should have gravity "Center" for its content (not layout gravity).

Try do this:

```
for (Games  game : Games.values()) {
                TableRow newRow = new TableRow(this);
                newRow.setLayoutParams(tableRowParams);

TableRow.LayoutParams params2 = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                params2.weight = .8f;
                params2.gravity= Gravity.CENTER;

                String[] words = game.name().split("(?=[A-Z])");
                String name = "";
                for (String word : words) {
                    if(word.length() < 1) continue;
                    name += word + "\n";
                }

                tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setTextSize(fontSize);
                tv.setText(name);
                tv.setLayoutParams(params2);
                newRow.addView(tv);
                newRow.setWeightSum(6);

                for (Level level : Level.values()) {
                    ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);

                    iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
                    iv.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                    iv.setLayoutParams(params);

                    tv = new TextView(this);
                    tv.setLayoutParams(params);
                    tv.setText("EASY");
                    tv.setTextSize(fontSize);

                    if( acheivements.getPassed(level, game) )//has achievement
                    {
                        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.star_gold_full_small);
                    }
                    else {
                        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.star_gold_empty_small);
                    }
                    newRow.addView(tv);
                }
                tbLayout.addView(newRow);
            }
```

In this code i have created new layout params as params2 because the textview was using weight of 1 so that your images were little right sided. i had used .8f weight for the names so now its working ok. so do as per your req. 
Hope it Helps!!

Comment: post your image please so i can identify the prob.

Comment: I updated again with two images , one has text and one has stars(imageviews). You can see that the text aligns and the image does not.It was missing weightsum on new row which i added, also it was adding a blank line to the top of the game name which i removed.

Comment: set gravity to center in tablerow for imageviews and also use weight as used in textview so that both will get same space allocation and can be align same. and if you can provide me code then i can help you with that.

Comment: you have used gravity left for headers thats why its not aligned. set them to center.

Comment: yes i tried setting them to center but made no difference, the text aligns the stars do not , it must be to do with alignment of images.

Comment: I fixed the problem , see my updated question. Cant believe how long i have spent on something that should be easy.

Comment: I tried your solution and it works too, the stars are center aligned. Thanks for your help

Comment: @tsukimi i took about an hour either because nothing else worked, kudos for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a minimal solution based on the above comments:

```
<ImageView
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"

    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/cross" />
```

The first half containes the attributes that seem to be necessary to solve the problem.